# I can't insert it into the database with node.js when I need to put some variable of type DATE

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When I run node.js it is giving error when inserting in the table.
I've tried to change the date format but to no avail

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'registros'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) console.error('Erro ao conectar com o BD: ' + err.stack);
    return;
});

connection.query("insert into cadastro (Prontuario, Nome_Paciente, Nome_Responsavel, Data_Nascimento, Data_Solicitacao, Data_Atendimento, Data_Entrega, Observacao) values (987054, 'Thiago Silva', 'Maria Jose', '2000-04-02', '2020-10-18', '2020-04-04', '2020-10-20', 'Paciente solicitou BPA');",function(err, result){
    if(!err){
        console.log('Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!');
    }else{
        console.log('Erro ao cadastrar o usuario');
    }
})
```

The table was created this way:

```
create table cadastro (
Prontuario DOUBLE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Nome_Paciente VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Nome_Responsavel VARCHAR(60),
Data_Nascimento DATE,
Data_Solicitacao DATE,
Data_Atendimento DATE,
Data_Entrega DATE,
Observacao VARCHAR(200)
);
```

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: When I run node index.js to insert the query in the database it gives an error, however when I put the same script in the workbench it will normally

Comment: Provide the error you are getting from the workbench

Comment: Debugger attached.
Process exited with code 1
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\app.js
Error
app.js:19

Comment: Is just displaying the error message that I had displayed on the console.log in case of errors in the input of the table

Comment: Sorry. I can't see where or what you attached.

Answer (score 0):

When running the code exactly as you've inserted it, I get a success message from the application claiming:

> Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!

I can also see the created entry in the table `cadastro` of my database.

I'm guessing your error is probably due to a failure to connect with the database itself, have you verified that it's running and double checked the credentials to make sure they match?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the primary key that I forgot to change, I remembered to give a console.log in err and he accused the problem ... Beginner error